# Fragments not being displayed correctly on android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating a budgeting app in Android. Currently, I'm trying to use `fragments` to display all of the users' current wallets (one fragment per wallet). Each `fragment` will take up the whole screen and use a `TabLayout` at the top of the screen for navigation. Since my `fragments` are displaying data that is going to be changed often, they need to be dynamic. The issue right now is that they are being created (I can see them in the `FragmentManager` using breakpoints etc), however, they aren't being displayed in the `ViewPager` or the `TabLayout`.

My XML code for the main activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorTest"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/createWallet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create wallet"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/currentFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Current Fragment"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/createWallet"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My code for creating the `fragments` and tying the `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` together in `MainActivity`:

```
ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

public void loadFragments()
{
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);

    for (int i = 0; i < walletList.size(); i++)
    {
        WalletClass object = walletList.get(i);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment frag = new fragment().newInstance(object);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.pager, frag, "fragment" + i);
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(frag); // this line can cause crashes
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

My fragment class code:

```
public fragment newInstance(WalletClass wallet)
{
    fragment frag = new fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("walletName", wallet.getWalletName());
    bundle.putInt("walletBalance", wallet.getBalance());

    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    return frag;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + bundle.getString("walletName"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    TextView walletName = view.findViewById(R.id.walletName);
    walletName.setText(bundle.getString("walletName"));

    return view;
}
```

And my code for the `ViewPager` adapter. This code is mostly from some other tutorials online mashed together, this is essentially what needs to be reworked I think:

```
List<fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>(); // this line can cause crashes
List<String> fragmentNameList = new ArrayList<>();

private Context context;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context)
{
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public fragment getItem(int position)
{
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

public void addFragment (Fragment fragment, WalletClass wallet) // this line can cause crashes
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("walletName", wallet.getWalletName());
    bundle.putInt("walletBalance", wallet.getBalance());
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    fragmentNameList.add(wallet.getWalletName());
}

public void removeFragment (fragment fragment)
{
    fragmentList.remove(fragment);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return fragmentList.size();
}

@Nullable
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
{
    return fragmentNameList.get(position);
}
```

So does anyone have any ideas about how to create `fragments` dynamically with a `ViewPager` adapter? Or am I doing this the completely wrong way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your `fragment` not attached properly to your `ViewPager`.

**First**, in your `loadFragment()` your new added Fragment has not been set on your `viewPager`. you have to add `setAdapter()` again after adding new fragment to your adapter. As mentioned in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView) (it's from ListAdapter class, but it fundamentally same):

> In order to display items in the list, call setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) to associate an adapter with the list.

**Second**, also in your `loadFragment()`, you don't have to create a new `ViewPagerAdapter` instance inside the method. Use your viewPagerAdapter that you instantiate early. And as long you declare ViewPager in the beginning outside your `onCreate()` method.

**Third**, you may want to remove your `FragmentTransaction` in `loadFragment()`.  I don't know if it means to be or not. But, as long as you have adapter, your new fragment could attached automatically without calling `FragmentTransaction`

Here what `MainActivity` looks like:

```java
// declare ViewPager viewPager in the beginning of class.
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

public void loadFragments()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < walletList.size(); i++)
    {
        WalletClass object = walletList.get(i);

        fragment frag = new fragment().newInstance(object);
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(frag, object);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter)
    }
}
```

*Note*: When I ran your code, I think the problem is not your Adapter but the way you call your adapter

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

FragmentPagerAdapter already manages the lifecycle of Fragments, you wouldn't need to add them manually. However, FragmentPagerAdapter encodes the position of a Fragment into its fragment tag, so it cannot be safely used to handle dynamic pager adapters.

You need to use the following code, or equivalent (that would probably end up to be the following code), based on code of FragmentPagerAdapter.

```
public class DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter";

    private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public static abstract class FragmentIdentifier implements Parcelable {
        private final String fragmentTag;
        private final Bundle args;

        public FragmentIdentifier(@NonNull String fragmentTag, @Nullable Bundle args) {
            this.fragmentTag = fragmentTag;
            this.args = args;
        }

        protected FragmentIdentifier(Parcel in) {
            fragmentTag = in.readString();
            args = in.readBundle(getClass().getClassLoader());
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(fragmentTag);
            dest.writeBundle(args);
        }

        protected final Fragment newFragment() {
            Fragment fragment = createFragment();
            Bundle oldArgs = fragment.getArguments();
            Bundle newArgs = new Bundle();
            if(oldArgs != null) {
                newArgs.putAll(oldArgs);
            }
            if(args != null) {
                newArgs.putAll(args);
            }
            fragment.setArguments(newArgs);
            return fragment;
        }

        protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
    }

    private ArrayList<FragmentIdentifier> fragmentIdentifiers = new ArrayList<>();

    private FragmentTransaction currentTransaction = null;

    private Fragment currentPrimaryItem = null;

    public DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    private int findIndexIfAdded(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        for (int i = 0, size = fragmentIdentifiers.size(); i < size; i++) {
            FragmentIdentifier identifier = fragmentIdentifiers.get(i);
            if (identifier.fragmentTag.equals(fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void addFragment(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        if (findIndexIfAdded(fragmentIdentifier) < 0) {
            fragmentIdentifiers.add(fragmentIdentifier);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void removeFragment(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        int index = findIndexIfAdded(fragmentIdentifier);
        if (index >= 0) {
            fragmentIdentifiers.remove(index);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentIdentifiers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(@NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        if (container.getId() == View.NO_ID) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager with adapter " + this
                    + " requires a view id");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        if (currentTransaction == null) {
            currentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        final FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier = fragmentIdentifiers.get(position);
        // Do we already have this fragment?
        final String name = fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag;
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if (fragment != null) {
            currentTransaction.attach(fragment);
        } else {
            fragment = fragmentIdentifier.newFragment();
            currentTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment, fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag);
        }
        if (fragment != currentPrimaryItem) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        if (currentTransaction == null) {
            currentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        currentTransaction.detach((Fragment) object);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
        if (fragment != currentPrimaryItem) {
            if (currentPrimaryItem != null) {
                currentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
                currentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
            }
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            currentPrimaryItem = fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(@NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        if (currentTransaction != null) {
            currentTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
            currentTransaction = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return ((Fragment) object).getView() == view;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("fragmentIdentifiers", fragmentIdentifiers);
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        Bundle bundle = ((Bundle)state);
        bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
        fragmentIdentifiers = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("fragmentIdentifiers");
    }
}
```

Then you can pass in `FragmentIdentifier`s into this pager, which will properly manage your fragments based on your fragment identifiers.

> ```
>  List<fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

Those tutorials are trying to make your app crash, check #3 in https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just trying to work my way through it and understand. When you say I can now just pass in FragmentIdentifiers into the pager, do you mean somehow pass it into the ViewPagerAdapter? And what exactly is the FragmentIdentifiers I should pass? (I haven't used abstract classes before and have limited knowledge of them)

Comment: To make Dynamic FragmentPagerAdapter work (as in this code I copied in for you and thankfully you don't have to write yourself), you have to instantiate a `DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter`, add the fragment identifiers (where each fragment you want to show, you'd extend the FragmentIdentifier for it and override its method `newFragment` to create a new instance of that Fragment), then set the adapter to the ViewPager. It should work first try after that. If you need to remove a Fragment, then you'd remove its FragmentIdentifier.